# what is wrong in my answer and what will be the correct solution for this probability question ?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving, conditional-probability

A and B play a game where each is asked to select a number from 1 to 5. If 
the two numbers match, both of them win a prize. The probability that they 
will not win a prize in a single trial is - 
a)1/25 b) 24/25 c)2/25 d)23/25

My proposed solution - Total number of ways in which both of them can select a number each:
=5×5=25
total number of ways in which two numbers match that is (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5) = 5
probability that they will not win a prize = 1 - 5/25  = 4/5.
Tell me what is wrong in my answer and what will be the correct solution ?

Comment: Well, we can eliminate choices a and c easily because it is unlikely for them to win, so there is a high chance of them "not winning." You seem to be correct, as I am interpreting the problem the same way you are. Are you sure of the wording? Do both A and B pick independently? Is one of them forced to pick a certain value?

Comment: Check the wording of the question carefully - are the numbers supposed to match a random number chosen by the games master? Also the probability depends on whether they are able to co-operate or not.

Comment: If I am A and I don't know what B picks, I still wouldn't pick randomly because there is a possibility that B wouldn't pick randomly either, and so I would pick "1" because that is the simplest. If B thinks like me then we would win all the time.

Comment: answer is 1/25 given with solution ...here is the link
http://www.lofoya.com/Aptitude-Questions-And-Answers/Probability/l2p5.htm
in above link see question number 24 and explain me how they have solved .

Comment: Your answer is correct, it must be 4/5. That question's discussion also has raised the same objection.

Answer (score 1):

The rationale behind the solution is this:

The game conductor has a particular number from 1 to 5 that he wants A and B to pick.  Let us say "2". Then

P(A picking 2) $= \frac{1}{5}$

P(B picking 2) $= \frac{1}{5}$

P(A picking other than 2) $= \frac{4}{5}$

P(B picking other than 2) $= \frac{4}{5}$

P(Both picking 2) $= \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{5}$

P(A picks 2, B picks other than 2)$ = \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{4}{5}$

P(A picks other than 2, B picks 2) $= \frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{5}$

P(B picks other than 2, B picks other than 2)$ = \frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{4}{5}$

They don't win the game when the last three scenarios happen $= \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{4}{5}+\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{5}+\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{4}{5} = \frac{24}{25}$

They win the prize $= \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{5} = \frac{1}{25}$

Obviously, the question has been worded badly.  Your answer is correct for the wording of the question.

Thanks

Satish